# angular2 only shows "loading..." with selector

Tags: html, css, angular, indexing, css-selectors

I have my index.html setup with

```
<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
```

My app.component links to a templateUrl that displays login information. The HTML should have some colorful background and some images displaying with input tags.

```
ng.core.Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html', //directed from root
     styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css'] //directed from root
})
```

The only think my index will load is the "Loading..." portion. I have tried to remove it and then it is merely blank.

What have I forgotten to add to make this load the HTML that I actually want to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open a developer console and see the errors. Use the keyboard shortcuts. On Windows and Linux: Ctrl + Shift + J. On Mac: Cmd + Option + J.
2. Go to the 'Console' tab and check errors.

Comment: Looks like the newest version of zone.js (0.5.15) was causing me errors. I've reverted back to 0.8.4 and things began to work again!